# SilverStripe Tinymce configuration not updating inside module

Tags: php, tinymce, silverstripe

We have a boilerplate module that we include on all of your SilverStripe builds. We are attempting to add a new class to our customised WYSIWYG config.

The weird thing is that we have a module dedicated to this but as soon as we move this configuration out of that module and into the new module, the config reflects only a couple of the changes and not all.

Example:

**wysiwygboilerplate/_config.php**

[image]

**companyname-boilerplate/_config.php**
[image]

The first example shows the correct wysiwyg configuration. When that same code is moved to the new location 'companyname-boilerplate/' directory it ceases to function.

This is the snippet of code I am working with. (with the only update being the path to content css)

```
//-------------------------------------------- WYSIWYG config

$defaultEditorConfig = HtmlEditorConfig::get('cms');
$defaultEditorConfig->setOptions(
    array(
        'theme'                         => 'advanced',
        'priority'                      => 1,
        'browser_spellcheck'            => true,
        'body_class'                    => 'wysiwyg',
        'content_css'                   => '/companyname-boilerplate/styles/wysiwyg.css',
        'schema'                        => 'html5',
        'extended_valid_elements'       => 'figure,figcaption',
        'end_container_on_empty_block'  => true,
        'style_formats'                 => array(
            array(
                'title'     => 'H1',
                'block'     => 'h1'
            ),
            array(
                'title'     => 'H2',
                'block'     => 'h2'
            ),
            array(
                'title'     => 'H3',
                'block'     => 'h3'
            ),
            array(
                'title'     => 'H4',
                'block'     => 'h4'
            ),
            array(
                'title'     => 'H5',
                'block'     => 'h5'
            ),
            array(
                'title'     => 'Paragraph',
                'block'     => 'p'
            ),
            array(
                'title'     => 'Blockquote',
                'block'     => 'blockquote',
                'wrapper'   => true
            ),
            array(
                'title'     => 'Figure',
                'block'     => 'figure',
                'wrapper'   => true
            ),
            array(
                'title'     => 'Figure caption',
                'block'     => 'figcaption',
                'wrapper'   => true
            )
        )
    )
);

$defaultEditorConfig->disablePlugins('contextmenu');
$defaultEditorConfig->enablePlugins('lists', 'paste');
$defaultEditorConfig->setButtonsForLine(1, 'styleselect, formatselect, separator, bold, italic, separator, justifyleft, justifycenter, justifyright, separator, bullist, numlist, separator, charmap, ssmedia, separator, sslink, unlink, separator, code');
$defaultEditorConfig->setButtonsForLine(2);
$defaultEditorConfig->setButtonsForLine(3);
```

My initial thoughts are that this is to do with the order SilverStripe is loading the configuration files, but there are no other files / modules that define a HtmlEditorConfig that I am aware of.

The other thought I had was around caching, I cleared out the SilverStripe cache, my browser cache and even ran a dev/build with still no joy, so that rules out caching

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the modules config are included in alphabetical order you either have to rename your boilerplate module (or the installation dir in composer.json) that it comes after `framework` or put the config inside `mysite` manually, cause `mysite` is added at last and there you can overwrite settings.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! So modules can only be loaded in Alphabetical order?! That is horrid... This takes me back to the old days of naming your business 'AAAA Company' to get to the top of the phone directory. Is there no way to give a module priority manually (other than putting all config into the mysite directory)?

Comment: It doesn't matter normally, cause you can define in your yml config what other configs should be loaded before. So overwriting something is easy - in yml.
unfortunately htmleditor doesn't use yml :(
feel free to file an issue at github https://github.com/silverstripe/silverstripe-framework/issues

Comment: I submitted a pull request yesterday, for adding another class in the image aligment dropdown in the htmleditor. The guys responded saying that it would be good for these to be updatable through yml but sdaly is not at the moment. They suggested somebody look into it. I know very little about the inner workings of SilverStripe and how the yml files work but will give this a crack when I get some time. https://github.com/silverstripe/silverstripe-framework/pull/3616#event-191107450 thanks again for your help understanding this.